# Docker arg not being read correctly from command line

Tags: docker

Using this command to start and run my docker container passing in argument ./target/myapp-SNAPSHOT.jar where ./target/myapp-SNAPSHOT.jar is the Spring boot app I wish to run :

```
docker build -t foo . && docker run -it foo -e J_FILE=./target/myapp-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I receive error :

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:alpine-jre

LABEL app.name="test"
LABEL app.type="test"

ARG J_FILE
ADD ${J_FILE} /myapp.jar

COPY J_FILE /myapp.jar

COPY startup.sh /
RUN chmod +x startup.sh;

ENTRYPOINT ["/startup.sh"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

startup.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh

JAVA_HEAP_INITIAL=384m
JAVA_HEAP_MAX=768m
JAVA_METASPACE_MAX=128m

java -jar /app.jar
```

If I change `Dockerfile` to explicitly copy the jar file :

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:alpine-jre

LABEL app.name="test"
LABEL app.type="test"

COPY ./target/myapp-SNAPSHOT.jar /myapp.jar

COPY startup.sh /
RUN chmod +x startup.sh;

ENTRYPOINT ["/startup.sh"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

The app starts as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ARG` flag in `Dockerfile` is meant for configuration when [building](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) a docker image. It will not have any effect when you run the container.

Therefore, you should update your command to be like this:

```
docker build --build-arg J_FILE=./target/myapp-SNAPSHOT.jar -t foo . && docker run -it foo
```

You can also update your `Dockerfile` to be like this:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:alpine-jre

LABEL app.name="test"
LABEL app.type="test"

ARG J_FILE=./target/myapp-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY ${J_FILE} /myapp.jar

COPY startup.sh /
RUN chmod +x startup.sh;

ENTRYPOINT ["/startup.sh"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

Note 2 changes in the file above:

1. Use `COPY` instead of `ADD`
2. Set the default value for `J_FILE` as `./target/myapp-SNAPSHOT.jar` in case the `--build-arg` is not passed with the `docker build` command.